# DTrace key logger

Tags: macos, keylistener, dtrace

I have tried to see if I could get Brendan Gregg's sshkeysnoop.d to work on Mac OS X, but am having trouble. Is it possible to get this working? If so, how?

The error I am getting is:

```
dtrace: failed to compile script ./sshkeysnoop.d: line 40: probe description syscall::exec:return does not match any probes
```

Is it possible to do any other kind of key logging on Mac OS X using DTrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things you can do to adapt scripts like this. First, you can ask `dtrace` what probe points it has:

```
$ sudo dtrace -l -f 'syscall::exec*'
   ID   PROVIDER            MODULE                          FUNCTION NAME
18442    syscall                                              execve entry
18443    syscall                                              execve return
```

Second, you can trace all syscalls on a single process to see what's going on.

```
$ sudo dtruss ssh somewhere 2>dtrussout
Password: (type something here)
```

If you look through `dtrussout` you can see

```
read_nocancel(0x5, "a\0", 0x1)       = 1 0
read_nocancel(0x5, "s\0", 0x1)       = 1 0
read_nocancel(0x5, "d\0", 0x1)       = 1 0
read_nocancel(0x5, "f\0", 0x1)       = 1 0
read_nocancel(0x5, "\n\0", 0x1)      = 1 0
```

With that knowledge, it's pretty easy to adapt the script.

```
$ diff sshkeysnoop.d{.orig,}
40c40
< syscall::exec:return, syscall::exece:return
---
> syscall::execve:return
51c51
< syscall::open:entry, syscall::open64:entry
---
> syscall::open:entry
58c58
< syscall::open:return, syscall::open64:return
---
> syscall::open:return
68c68
< syscall::read:entry
---
> syscall::read_nocancel:entry
75c75
< syscall::read:return
---
> syscall::read_nocancel:return
```

Answer (score 1):

OS X does not have a syscall::exec DTrace probe. It does have a syscall::execve though. Similarly it doesn't have syscall::open64, which is also used in this script. However, even with replacing exec with execve and removing open64, the script doesn't function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you are loading with the all option

```
kldload dtraceall
```

and not just

```
kldload dtrace
```

Or the syscalls are not going to get loaded.